# I dont want to upload my dart packages to pub.dev but I want to share them effectively with my team

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub, pub.dev

So lately we started creating our own dart packages and want to share them effectively (if someone updates it everyone can just pull the newest version with the pub command) So I was wondeing if it would be possible to host our own little "pub.dev" just for us and to configure pub so that it pulls the packages from there

I have no plan on where to start or how to make such a thing

Comment: Try unpub https://pub.dev/packages/unpub

Answer (score 1):

You can upload package to your company's GitHub and in pubspec.yaml you can import it as:

```
  package:
    git: https://github.com/user/package.git
    ref: main
```

Or use https://pub.dev/packages/unpub to host your private Pub server.